# It's not the same color as the one I see

Tags: materials

I've designated material as gray, but what I see is blue.
I installed the lights, adjusted the color management, and it's blue.
Why does it look blue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it’s an illusion. Render it and click and hold on that area to see a color readout at the bottom of the editor.

Comment: There's no problem with the render, but it's blue on the viewport.

Comment: I've made a screenshot and picked the color, it is not blue, you don't have any blue light and your HDRI isn't blue, maybe it's your screen?

Comment: or maybe the eyes....:D

Comment: Do you mean the tie? There is indeed a tiny blueish tint. #9E9E9E is the color in the shader. The color from a screenshot of the material preview is #9b9b9e (RGB). You have really good eyes if you can see this difference. I have no idea why there is a difference.

Comment: I think my eyes are sensitive. Thank you for your answer.